# open file specified via environment variable

Tags: variables, find-file, environment

Environment variables that points to specific location are of common occurrence. `$HOME`, `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`, `%LOCALAPPDATA%` and many more. It is pretty convenient to open files (and directories) just by typing appropriate variable name.

So I'm searching for a function that could find file (directory) by environment variable name. Generic string expansion in the command buffer could be another option.

Comment: The values of environment variables can be retrieved in emacs using e.g. `(getenv "HOME")`. When trying to open a file with `C-x C-f` you can type `$HOME/foo` in the minibuffer: that will open the file `foo` in your home directory. For other cases, see `expand-file-name` and `substitute-in-file-name`: a common idiom is `(expand-file-name (substitute-in-file-name "$HOME/foo"))`.

Comment: Shame on me, I tried string expansion in minibuffer and failed. But that was a typo.  Actually it all works and my question is irrelevant.

Comment: Been there, done that :-) Glad it worked out in the end.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is only based on a usage-error. The questioner has clarified this himself in his own comment.